# Error starting Pycharm on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, pycharm, ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-platform

I have installed pycharm on a google cloud VM with Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed pycharm and tried to open it but i get the error :

```
root@ubuntu1604-4cpu:~# pycharm-community
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

I read that it could be because of open java but my java environment is fine:

```
root@ubuntu1604-4cpu:~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

There is no access issue either, I have run it both as sudo and my user..  i installed even nvidia graphics driver to be sure..

nothing seems to working..

Any help is much appreciated.. thanks a million :)

Regards,

Comment: Are you able to start any graphical application, like xeyes or xterm for example?

Comment: @GhostCat: I havent installed them on my instance yet..

Comment: Are you able to run any graphical program? Those were just examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can try executing `export DISPLAY=:0.0` in bash before starting PyCharm.

Comment: it says:                                                                                                       
    Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment
    java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as 
    the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: @thealchemist try installing X11 gui on that machine: `sudo apt-get install xorg`. Here are the canonical docs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

Comment: I did it actually.. after I got the error.. I am still getting the same error.. :/

Comment: @thealchemist how are you connecting to this instance?

Comment: Ssh has options like -x or -X (never can remember that) that you have to use to allow x11 forwarding. But are you sure you really want to run an IDE on a remote system far away? The latency might probably be enormous...

Comment: @thealchemist then I suppose you need an ssh client that supports GUI and can run X11 locally for the remote node to be able to connect to it